# Read word file, fill some text and create a file word in nodejs

Tags: node.js, docx

I'm currently having a problem with NodeJS thanks for the help pro.
We need to write a module read word file header and footer then fill in the necessary fields in a number of positions then download the word file. I have read the file using the word-extractor library but are having difficulty converting the readings back to the word file (I see lib officegen so strong, but it not support). Have you ever encountered this situation or know the fix to help you with. 
Thank you for spending time with me

Comment: I solved the problem, this is my solution. If anyone needs to refer to:

Comment: https://docxtemplater.readthedocs.io/en/latest/generate.html#node

Comment: http://javascript-ninja.fr/docxtemplater/v1/examples/demo.html#rawxml